# facebook batch/fql friendlists a friend is member of

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-batch-request

I'm creating a javascript facebook app to have an overview of my friendlists. Actually I can retrieve my (logged in user = me) friendlists, when I click a friendlist I see all my friends in that list.

When I want now is, when I click a list, I want to see the friends belonging to that list, and a comma separated lists my friend is member of.

For example in the list **"Best"** I have 3 friends: **Athos, Portos, Aramis**. But they are also in other lists. So in my app I'd like to get something like this:

- **Athos**: Best, Family, Close Friends, VIP
- **Portos**: Best, VIP
- **Aramis**: Best, Close Friends, Party Animals

I tried with the FQL multiquery, but it seems impossible to get what I want.

So I think I should use a Batch request, but since I don't have a lot of experience using batches here I am asking your help.

So here the FQL query I use to get friends belonging to the list. I need this, because I want to manage friends beginning from a list:

```js
var listID = 123;//just enter a listID
var friendsInList = 'SELECT uid,username,profile_url,first_name,last_name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid =' + listID +')';
```

Now I don't know how to proceed in a clean and efficient way. I have a working but inefficient solution:

```js
//[...]FB.api call to get a response object with all my friends using the friendsInList query above
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    friendID = response[i].uid;
    //call FB.api with the following query:
    var friendListMemberships = 'SELECT uid, flid, name FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM friendlist WHERE owner=me()) AND uid IN (select uid FROM friendlist WHERE flid =' + friendID;
}
```

the above solution works but is highly inefficient as I send a FB.api request for each friend, very slow for big lists... thus I'd like a pro user to help me putting this in a [batch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/batch-requests/) (a batch can have maximum 50 requests, thus I'd like to send just 1-2 requests and get back all what I need).

I know how to write a batch, here I put the structure of my code, if it can help you completing it with the second query:

```js
var listID = _listID;

var _queryFriendsInList = 'SELECT uid,username,profile_url,first_name,last_name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid =' + listID + ')';

var queryFriendsInList = _queryFriendsInList.replace(" ", "+");

var _queryFriendListMemberships = 'I have no idea what kind of query I can write here to get the lists my friends from queryFriendsInList are member of';

var queryFriendListMemberships = _queryFriendListMemberships.replace(" ", "+");

var searchArgs = {
    access_token: FB.getAuthResponse().access_token,
    batch: []
};

searchArgs.batch.push({
    'method': 'GET',
    'name': 'friendsInList',
    'relative_url': 'method/fql.query?query=' + queryFriendsInList,
    'omit_response_on_success': false
});

//here is where I need help
searchArgs.batch.push({
    'method': 'GET',
    'name': 'friendlistMememberships',
    'relative_url': 'method/fql.query?query=' + queryFriendListMemberships,
    'omit_response_on_success': false
});

FB.api("/", "POST", searchArgs,
function (response) {
    //console.log("log");
}
);
```

I hope the question and code samples are clear enough. Thank you for helping!

Comment: How about getting friends and friendlists first, and then put the data together client-side? I’d think that’d be more efficient than trying to do it via API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get everything you want in one API call with a multiquery. You'll need to assemble this together on the client side with a few loops, but it shouldn't be too hard. Here's the query:

```
{
"all_friendlists":
    "SELECT flid, owner, name FROM friendlist WHERE owner=me()",
"fl_members":
   "SELECT uid, flid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid IN 
      (SELECT flid FROM #all_friendlists)",
"fl_member_details":
   "SELECT uid, name, username FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #fl_members)" 
}
```

You can present everything to your user from this one API call. The `#all_friendlists` query gives all your user's friendlists. Once your user has selected a friendlist, then loop through `#fl_members` to find all the members of this list, retrieving their details from `#fl_member_details`. Make another loop through `#fl_members` to find what other lists they belong to.

Alternately, you could just mash these three lists together into a single presentation page, and use a jQuery data filtering scheme like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) to allow your user to sort/filter/etc. on the fly.

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't think I could achieve the goal like this. I wanted to use the "lazy" way by issuing a request to FB for each click. As you suggested I initially get everything, save in some array of objects and work on those ones in the client with no interaction with FB anymore. Disadvantage: to manually update these "cache" arrays everytime I'll do an operation such deleting a friend from a list, adding one etc. but like this I'll for sure improve my javascrpt skills. About isotope (had no time to give it a try), can we say it's similar to jquery templates? Thanks again!

Comment: Take a quick look at the isotope website. It's not really similar to anything else out there. Yes, if you're updating friendlists based on this, you'll have to grab everything again, but it's still just 1 API call, so even that should go quick.

Comment: cpilko: thx again - fyi you can see the solution in action, with isotope filtering & animations in my new app here (previously "sandbox" now it's public you can test it): friendsmanager.pbworks.org